# A trigonometric identity with sines of double angles

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove : $$\frac{\tan(A+B)}{\tan(A-B)}= \frac{\sin(2A)+\sin(2B)}{\sin(2A)-\sin(2B)}$$

I'm stuck at substituting all double angles with $2\sin\cos$.

Solving for RHS.

$$
\frac{\sin(2A)+\sin(2B)}{\sin(2A)-\sin(2B)} = 
\frac{2\sin A\cos A + 2\sin B\cos B}{2\sin A\cos A - 2\sin B\cos B}
= \frac{2(\sin A\cos A +\sin B\cos B)}{ 2(\sin A\cos A - \sin B\cos B)}
=\frac{ \sin A\cos A +\sin B\cos B}{\sin A\cos A - \sin B\cos B}$$

I'm stuck there. I don't know what to substitute from here. I tried to use wolframalpha as my reference but I don't know what formula was used.

Can anybody shed light on this one? Thanks in Advance !

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started from the left hand side, and finished at the right hand side of your identity. This may be what your teacher wanted.

\begin{align}
\frac{\tan(A+B)}{\tan(A-B)} &= \frac{\frac{\tan A + \tan B}{1 - \tan A \tan B}}{\frac{\tan A - \tan B}{1 + \tan A \tan B}}  \\
&= \frac{\tan A + \tan B}{1 - \tan A \tan B} \cdot \frac{1 + \tan A \tan B}{\tan A - \tan B}  \\
&= \frac{\frac{\sin A}{\cos A} + \frac{\sin B}{\cos B}}{1 - \frac{\sin A}{\cos A} \frac{\sin B}{\cos B}} \cdot \frac{1 + \frac{\sin A}{\cos A} \frac{\sin B}{\cos B}}{\frac{\sin A}{\cos A} - \frac{\sin B}{\cos B}}  \\
&= \frac{\frac{\sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B}{\cos A \cos B}}{\frac{\cos A \cos B - \sin A \sin B}{\cos A \cos B}} \cdot \frac{\frac{\cos A \cos B + \sin A \sin B}{\cos A \cos B}}{\frac{\sin A \cos B - \cos A \sin B}{\cos A \cos B}}  \\
&= \frac{\sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B}{\cos A \cos B-\sin A \sin B} \cdot \frac{\cos A \cos B + \sin A \sin B}{\sin A \cos B - \cos A \sin B} \\
&= \frac{\sin A \cos A \cos^2 B+\sin B \cos B \sin^2 A + \sin B \cos B \cos^2 A + \sin A \cos A \sin^2 B}{\sin A \cos A \cos^2 B - \sin B \cos B \cos^2 A - \sin B \cos B \sin^2 A + \sin A \cos A \sin^2 B} \\
&= \frac{\sin A \cos A(\cos^2 B + \sin^2 B)+\sin B \cos B(\sin^2 A + \cos^2 A)}{\sin A \cos A(\cos^2 B +\sin^2 B)-\sin B \cos B(\cos^2 A + \sin^2 A)} \\
&= \frac{\sin A \cos A+\sin B \cos B}{\sin A \cos A - \sin B \cos B} \\
&= \frac{\frac 12\sin(2A)+\frac 12 \sin (2B)}{\frac 12 \sin(2A)-\frac 12 \sin (2B)} \\
&= \frac{\sin(2A)+\sin (2B)}{\sin(2A)-\sin (2B)} 
\end{align}

Comment: Well that is exactly what i need. I was wrong to use the right side.  Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Using 
[Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html), $$\sin2A+\sin2B=2\sin(A+B)\cos(A-B)$$  and $$\sin2A-\sin2B=\cdots$$

---

From the LHS $$\frac{\tan(A+B)}{\tan(A-B)}=\frac{\sin(A+B)\cos(A-B)}{\cos(A+B)\sin(A-B)}$$

Now apply [Werner Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html)

Comment: Wow i did not know about that. What part of the Trig. Identities does that belong? Thanks Good sir.

Comment: @Niko, Welcome. But not sure about "What part?"

Comment: I found it thanks to your link. My teacher didn't teach that to us. It becomes clearer now. Thank you very much !

Comment: @Niko, My Pleasure. Observe that there are two set of formulae : one can be derived from the other

Comment: In case your teacher wants you to stick to a smaller set of identities, you could also use the sum and difference of angles identities on the LHS, change to sines and cosines and the two sides will match with the work you have already done.